# Injectivity of a matrix function

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ be defined as follows:

$$f(X)=X\left(\int_0^\infty e^{Mt}(NX+X^TN^T+PP^T)e^{M^T t}dt\right)^{-1}$$

where $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is such that its eigenvalues have negative real part, $N \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ and $PP^T$ is positive definite. Is $f$ injective? Does the answer depend on $M,N,P?$ Bonus Question: is $f$ surjective?

Comment: What are the assumptions on $M,P,N$ ?
If these are just any matrices $f$ can be undefined.

Comment: $PP^T$ can be supposed to be positive definite. Notice that $f(X)=XZ^{-1}$, where Z solves $AZ+ZA^T+NX+X^TN^T+PP^T=0$. If $PP^T$ is positive definite, this matrix equation should admit a unique positive definite solution $Z$

Comment: What is $A$ in your equation ? And if $PP^T=Id$ and $M=Id$ then the integral seems undefined, am I missing something ?

Comment: Apologies, it was $MZ+ZM^T+NX+X^TN^T+PP^T=0$. Ok, I see, We need $M$'s eigenvalues have negative real part. I updated the question.

Comment: $f(aX)=f(X)$ for every $a$.

Comment: Why? $f(aX)=aX\left(\int_0^\infty e^{Mt}(aNX+aX^TN^T+PP^T)e^{M^Tt}dt\right)^{-1}\neq f(X)$, no?